# How to create a UIButton adjusting size to the image in it?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I use the storyboard to create a UIButton. The button contains an image. For iPhone6 plus the image is @3x, which has larger size than @2x. I hope the button can adjust size according to the image.

Please give me some advice on making this button, either using storyboard or programmatically.

Comment: add 3 images  .... image.png , image@2x.png , image@3x.png and then assign the image.png to your button in storyboard it will take the 3x and 2x images automatically when it will move to 3x device or 2x device as iPhone 6plus or 6 respectivlty

Answer (score 3):

For that you can use **`Images.xcassets`** file.

steps for that

1. Add new image set in Images.xcassets file.
2. Add images in box (@2x and @3x).
3. Give name to image set and use that name as image name of
       button.

Comment: such a small answer can be explained in comment but remember to get some rating you can either get negative

Comment: @FattiKhan you answer the question after 1hour while i post the answer.

And also you copy the contain of my about us.

Comment: simply NO , i just stated to give it a comment not to argue